# How to convert Unicode[Marathi] string in to byte array?

Tags: c#-4.0, encoding

I am trying to convert `unicode`[marathi] string in to `byte array`,but when I convert it and print, it shows **" ? ? ? ? ? ? "** like this.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

   public class Example
{
public static void Main()
{
    // Input string.
    const string input = "पांडुरंग";

    // Invoke GetBytes method.
    // ... You can store this array as a field!
   byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    // Loop through contents of the array.
    foreach (byte element in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element, (char)element);
    }
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

.

```
Output:
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
        63 = ?
```

if anyone have idea about this please help us.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`:

```
 byte[] array = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
```

Also, you are converting each byte to a separate char, whereas actually each character is represented by two bytes. The easiest way to get the chars from the byte array is to convert the bytes back to string using the same encoding, and calling GetCharArray() on the rsulting string:

```
    foreach (byte element in Encoding.Unicode.GetString(array).ToCharArray()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", element, (char)element);
    }
```

Comment: I also tried this,but displays output like this42 = *
9 =
62 = >
9 =
2 = ☻
9 =
33 = !
9 =
65 = A
9 =
48 = 0
9 =
2 = ☻
9 =
23 = ↨
9 =

Comment: As far as I know the Console is only Unicode enabled since VisualStudio 2013